# How to make different processes write in a common list and dataframe?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, multiprocessing

I have more than 1000 files which I would like to open and write the number of columns each file has into another dataframe. To speed up the process, I would like to use multiprocessing feature. Here is the code that I have written

```
import pandas as pd
import datetime
import os
import multiprocessing

all_files = os.listdir('E:\\2nd Set\\')
def cal(files,final_list):
    print(files)
    df = pd.read_csv('E:\\'+files)
    number_columns = df.shape[0]
    final_list.extend([files,number_columns])
    main_df.loc[main_df.shape[0]] = final_list


if __name__=='__main__':
    mgr = multiprocessing.Manager()
    main_list = mgr.list()
    p1 = multiprocessing.Pool()
    p = p1.map(cal,all_files,main_list)
    p1.start()
    p1.join()
```

On the execution of the above code, I am getting this error

> TypeError: '<=' not supported between instances of 'ListProxy' and 'int'

Also how to use a common dataframe

Comment: This is wrong in so many ways. First, `main_df` is not defined and cannot be shared across multiple processes. Second, the `map` method does not take three arguments. Third, your worker function `cal`, will only be passed a single file name. Fourth, your `read_csv` call is going against the wrong directory. Fifth, if you are running under Window, every process in the pool will needlessly be calling `os.listdir`. Sixth, Unless you have a super-duper solid state drive, you cannot achieve better performance doing all of these parallel I/O operations. Seventh, there is no `start` method on a pool.

Comment: I will calrify. The `map` method only takes a single *iterable* argument. It is interpreting `main_list` as the *chunksize* argument, which is supposed to be an integer, and that is why you are getting an exception. You need to be reading up on multiprocessing a bit more. This problem is also not the best fit for multiprocessing.

Answer (score 1):

Lots of issues here not least of which is the third parameter to *map()* which should be an *int* (chunk size). That's what's causing your problem

Comment: What will be the solution for this ? p = p1.map(cal,all_files,main_list)

Comment: The solution is for you to read the documentation https://docs.python.org/3.9/library/multiprocessing.html